# How to stop Backbone Event Bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In backbone I will often instantiate views using something like...

```
new mysite.some.namespace.View();
```

Which will then load in my view and attach events to the DOM.  The problem is with removing that view and then instantiating it again.  My events will often double if I load the view twice.  How can I eliminate this?  Is this because my el is set to a wrapper element for the app?

What's an easy solution for this?

Comment: Is it possible you are initializing a view to an element within a another view?  Hence, any bindings which apply to both the parent view and the subview would be called twice...

Comment: Are you properly calling `.remove()` on the view (and not overriding it)? It should clean up its events automatically.

Comment: @rudolph9 I am indeed loading a sub view in a master view and both of them do have the same "el"s.  I think that might be the issue.  I am not calling .remove() at all and if I do it destroys my app be removing the master view.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments it sounds like you have strayed off of the backbone straight and narrow path into the weeds. Proper event handling requires some care. If you post more code, we can provide more detailed suggestions, however:

- Make sure you are calling `.remove()` when you are done with a view instance. All DOM event bindings will be automatically removed.
- Don't do whacky things like having 2 view instances reference the same element (`this.el`).
- Do yourself a favor and don't mess with `this.el`. Don't specify it. Use `tagName` in your `extend` object if needed, but a view's `el` should be A) unique to that view and B) detached from the DOM until something external to the view attaches it (usually a router or composite view manager).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` in order to keep the event from propagating.